# Open source / freeware application for Windows 7 to create ISO images

Tags: windows-7, dvd, iso-image, compact-disc

I'm looking for a freely available utility I can run on Windows 7 to create CD/DVD ISO images from actual CDs and DVDs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By 'create', do you really mean you want to extract an ISO image from an existing CD/DVD?  'create' implies 'author' (from scratch) for some.

Comment: i meant 'extract' then

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Create is the correct word. A CD/DVD does not contain an ISO file. Yes, you can create an ISO from a folder too, and that is essentially the same process--taking a snapshot of the filesystem.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The program you could be looking for is [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/).

*From their home page:*

> ImgBurn is a lightweight CD / DVD / HD
>   DVD / Blu-ray burning application that
>   everyone should have in their toolkit!
>
> It has several 'Modes', each one for
>   performing a different task:
>
> - **Read - Read a disc to an image file**
> - Build - Create an image file from files on your computer or network - or you can write the files directly to a disc
> - Write - Write an image file to a disc
> - Verify - Check a disc is 100% readable. Optionally, you can also
>     have ImgBurn compare it against a
>     given image file to ensure the actual
>     data is correct
> - Discovery - Put your drive / media to the test! Used in combination
>     with DVDInfoPro, you can check the
>     quality of the burns your drive is
>     producing

[image]

Comment: Beware, the ImgBurn installer currently installs crap like "Search Protect" and "TuneUp utilities" by default, be sure to uncheck them during install...

Comment: Their website is a disaster. Can't work out how to download the thing.

Comment: +1 because this is the only mentioned software that can create an ISO from a **folder** source too. Apart from perhaps `dd`.

Comment: Google Chrome now blocks www.imgburn.com, someone should report this to them. I could not find their email address on the website.

Comment: Beware: the downloaded installer Setup_ImgBurn_2.5.8.0_dlm.exe contains a virus 'PUA/InstallCore (Cloud)'. Detected by Avira.

Answer (score 32):

[Infrarecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) is fantastic.  Does all that and then some, it's free, and works great.

[image]

Comment: And its GPL, which is nice.

Comment: +1 For an open source tool. That we we can be confident there is no maleware tacked on.

Answer (score 8):

[CDBurnerXP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) is also an excellent ISO creator as well as a complete CD/DVD burning application.

> CDBurnerXP is a free application to burn CDs and DVDs, including
>   Blu-Ray and HD-DVDs. It also includes the feature to burn and create
>   ISOs, as well as a multilanguage interface. Everyone, even companies,
>   can use it for free. It does not include adware or similar malicious
>   components.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I just checked out [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/) which worked out great for me but then I also needed to mount the ISO I created on a netbook and ran into [WinCDEmu](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/) to do so. As it turns out WinCDEmu seems also to have ISO creation capability too so I may begin to ditch trusty [daemontools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/downloads) in favor of this simplistic open-source and all inclusive tool.

If you haven't checked WinCDEmu out you should give it a try. Below is a feature list from their web page.

Features:

- One-click mounting of ISO, CUE, NRG, MDS/MDF, CCD, IMG images.
- Supports unlimited amount of virtual drives.
- Runs on 32-bit and 64-bit Windows versions from XP to Windows 7.
- **Allows creating ISO images through a context menu in Explorer.**
- Small installer size - less than 1MB!
- Does not require rebooting after installation.
- A special portable version is available.
- Translated to more than 20 languages.
- Does not occupy drive letters when not used.
- Supports data, DVD-video and BD-video images.
- WinCDEmu is free for any kind of use - it is licensed under LGPL

Comment: I just tried the portable version and it worked nicely. Pity the portable version doesn't seem to be able to create ISO images though.

Comment: And where is the source?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you [LC ISO Creator](http://www.lucersoft.com/freeware.php), as I've also done in these related questions:

> [How to make an image of a bootable dvd](https://superuser.com/questions/20536/how-to-make-an-image-of-a-bootable-dvd)
>   [What is the best way to make an ISO file out of a DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/17260/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-an-iso-file-out-of-a-dvd)

It's very small, lightweight, free and portable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Unix tools for Windows](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) contains mkisofs

Comment: if it doesn't it probably contains `dd`.

Comment: FYI: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/ is better and maintained in recent times.

Answer (score 0):

[ISO Recorder](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/) is simple choice that allows you to do this from the Explorer context menu.