# How can I move Works from my old laptop to its new replacement?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, microsoft-works

I have a Compaq Presario CQ62 with Windows 7 Home Paremium that is a few years old and while everything still works well, after much use/abuse I have broken the case below the keyboard. I just bought a Gateway LT4010u to replace it and I have already upgraded to Windows 7 Home Premium using the key from my old laptop. This upgrade process worked just fine.

Unfortunately, I'm running into trouble trying to get Microsoft Works from my old laptop onto my new one. The problem is that the new Gateway doesn't have a dvd drive. I was hoping there was a way to use my old laptop to load the program on the new one, possibly through the network (both connected via ethernet cable). I really don't like the idea of having to pay for Works for my new laptop when I already have it on the old one I am replacing.

Once I have every thing off the old laptop it will be going in the trash, so its not as though I am to cheat on the license. I just want to get what I have already paid for on the old equipment transferred to the new equipment. Any way to do this?

Comment: Microsoft Works is effectively dead. If you don't want to re-buy office, you're probably better off with OpenOffice/LibreOffice.

Comment: Agreed, though that wasn't the question of the poster. And if works came with the Compaq then there is a chance that its licensed only for that specific laptop.

Comment: @Hennes: "there is a chance that its licensed only for that specific laptop" - Right, as probably was OEM Win7 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating an image from the Microsoft Works DVD.
An image is basically a copy of the DVD.

On the new laptop you can then install a mounting software, with which you can emulate a DVD drive and insert the image file you previously created.

The operating system will then show a new (emulated) DVD drive. You will be able to install the software as if you would really have a DVD station on that laptop.

I suggest using ImgBurn to create an image of your DVD
[Open source / freeware application for Windows 7 to create ISO images](https://superuser.com/questions/23370/open-source-freeware-application-for-windows-7-to-create-iso-images)

I also suggest using Daemon Tools Lite to emulate a DVD station
http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/products/dtLite