# Is there any way to create Disk Image on Windows 7 without install any program?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

I want to create an Image disk on windows 7 OS , I know **Windows 8** and **BLUE** have built in virtual disk image (ISO Reader), but any way to create Virtual Disk image for ISO files in **Windows seven ultimate**?

*I mean I don't want install programs like Power ISO or Daemon Tools  and .... on my system but need their operation.*

Comment: Windows 8(.0) can mount ISO images too...

Comment: For existing CD/DVDs, or for files on the computer hard drive?

Comment: I mentioned it that i know but how is it possible in windows 7?

Comment: For existing CD/DVDs ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open source / freeware application for Windows 7 to create ISO images](http://superuser.com/questions/23370/open-source-freeware-application-for-windows-7-to-create-iso-images)

Comment: is this only way?

Comment: @user1592474 Yes. Built-in mounting of ISO images was only introduced in Windows 8.

Comment: Windows 7 can only natively mount VHD files.

Comment: @cybernard How?

Comment: @gparyani  Goto Manage then "Disk Management".  Right click on "Disk Management and select "Attach VHD"

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 does not include any ISO creation tool. You will need to use a third party program to create an ISO file.