# Making image of DVD for later compression?

Tags: windows, dvd, ripping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [opensource / freeware application for windows 7 to create ISO images](https://superuser.com/questions/23370/opensource-freeware-application-for-windows-7-to-create-iso-images)
>   [What is the best way to make an ISO file out of a DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/17260/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-an-iso-file-out-of-a-dvd)

I'm using Windows (Vista), and have no experience ripping DVDs, so this is a really newbie question.

To avoid having to take home a bunch of DVDs from the library, since I read it only takes a few minutes to make a copy on a hard-disk, I was thinking of just making an image of them on my laptop while still at the library, and perform the compression at home.

Is there a sure-fire way to clone a DVD for later processing, including sub-titles, menus, etc. so that I don't end up with unusable files back home?

Thank you.

Comment: you shouldn't copy DVDs you only borrowed...

Comment: We'll avoid the legal argument by just closing this as duplicate. You want to make a copy of a DVD, whatever dvd it is, you will find your answer on the other questions.

Comment: I sorta disagree its an exact duplicate - the other questions cover data - video DVDs are a fairly more annoying beast to deal with IMO

Comment: Yes, I was talking about movies, and from what I read, they seem to be more tricky to rip than data DVD's. Hence my question ;)

Comment: For those looking for the same information, I successfully ripped movies on DVD using DVD Decrypter and Handbrake. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

[doom9 has a nice howto on the whole process](http://www.doom9.org/index.html?/mpg/dvdshrink31-main.htm)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a good, supported solution for Windows is either DVDFab, or AnyDVD + CloneDVD.